# Strange mistake in Thymeleaf replace with variable

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have code:

```
<div 
            th:each="annotsField : ${annotsFields}"
        th:with="someVariable='admin/editElementsFromObjects/fragments/templateFor'+${annotsField.type()}+' :: templateFor'+${annotsField.type()}"

        >

        <div th:text="'!!!'+${someVariable}+'!!!'" />

        <!--<div th:replace="${someVariable}"  />-->
        <!--<div th:replace="admin/editElementsFromObjects/fragments/templateForString :: templateForString"  />-->

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
```

As you see, this code will print on the page something like !!!admin/editElementsFromObjects/fragments/templateForString :: templateForString!!! . OK.

But now we will uncomment code

```
<div th:replace="admin/editElementsFromObjects/fragments/templateForString :: templateForString"  />
```

It will include existing template file. OK. Good.

But why when I make code something like

```
<div 
                th:each="annotsField : ${annotsFields}"
                th:with="someVariable='admin/editElementsFromObjects/fragments/templateFor'+${annotsField.type()}+' :: templateFor'+${annotsField.type()}"

                >

                <div th:replace="${someVariable}"  />

                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
```

Then I got exception

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "admin/editElementsFromObjects/fragments/templateForString :: templateForString", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (admin/editElementsFromObjects/editForm:24)
```

Why it can't be included with code

```
<div th:replace="${someVariable}"  />
```

but included OK with code

```
<div th:replace="admin/editElementsFromObjects/fragments/templateForString :: templateForString"  />
```

and I don't see error in value of the my variable?..

Comment: Tried that also - same result. Tried pre/post processing - didn't help either. Try to post about it on thymeleaf forum or open an issue on github.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this using Thymeleaf 2.1.4 and it works if you reference the `replace` template using a preprocessor expression:

```
<div th:replace="__${someVariable}__" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**${someVariable}** as @Andrew describe works for me

I do this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33067572)